# Cat doesn't eat anything and shiver sometimes

Tags: cats, medicines

My pet, Cat is 05 months years old. It refused to eat anything it likes since last 03 days. Some times his breathing is noisy. I think he has phlegm.Many time it sleeps and shivers some times. I went to vet and no cure. What should be the disease? If there any medicines. please tell me. I am so helpless now.

Comment: take the cat to a vet right now dont waste any time go go go to the vet now.

Comment: I went. He gave saline and some injections. But it has no cure. There are some medicines such as syrups are here. Unable to soak. I used syringe feeding. Cat is so grumpy and scratching. :-(

Comment: i am realy sorry but there is very litle hope left for your cat,i realy hate to tell you this so again i am realy very sorry.

Comment: Isn't there any kind of remedy. I can't see it is dying. Please

Comment: i am crying right now and realy whish i could help you but i cant help it is sad but this is a part of loving any life,any animal or person it dont matter it is hard.

Comment: I can understand what you are saying. Thank You for your kindness. I am still doing what I can for it. I am trying to soak some medicines it. I hope that will be able to get a good result. God Bless

Comment: What was the vets diagnosis?

Comment: @trondhansen My pet died few hours ago. ;-(

Comment: @RebeccaRVT Vet said as symptoms of the cat are normal and gave some medicines. He didn't care more. We told that unable to soak medicines to cat. But Vet said, syrup is sweet and it will drink. But we couldn't soak. Are those symptoms can be spread to other cats?

Comment: i am realy sorry to hear this,try to take care of yourself you gave the cat a good life i am sure of it.many animals dont have a home and nobody to take care of them,you did your best and nobody can expect more of you.try to take care of yourself now.

Comment: Its hard to say if your cats illness will spread without diagnosis.

Comment: Closing this as it is too broad, these symptoms could be of anything - going to the vet hospital would be the right thing to do and you have done so, the veterinarian did not know what was wrong. Sorry about your kitty :(